# RTP: ⊢ $(A \to (A \to B)) \to (A \to B)$ using only primitive rules of natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

**Context:** Uni introductory predicate logic course question

I need to prove $(A \to (A \to B)) \to (A \to B)$ using only the primitive rules of natural deduction. I know that since I have no premises, any assumptions I make must be discharged by the end of the proof. The only way you can discharge assumptions is via arrow introduction or RAA (reductio ad absurdum). Since there's a bunch of arrows, my first guess was that I'd just be using a bunch of arrow introductions to discharge said assumptions, but having tried this a bunch of times (and either having assumptions not discharged or accidentally using formulas that aren't assumptions in my antecedent which is clearly a big no-no), I haven't been successful.

Does anyone have any hints/tips as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since I have no premises, any assumptions I make must be discharged by the end of the proof.

Correct.

> The only way you can discharge assumptions is via arrow introduction or RAA (*Reductio Ad Absurdum*). Since there's a bunch of arrows, my first guess was that I'd just be using a bunch of arrow introductions to discharge said assumptions.

Correct.

1. $A→(A→B)$ --- assumed [a]
2. $A$ --- assumed [b]
3. $A→B$ --- from 1) and 2) by $\to$-elim
4. $B$ --- from 2) and 3)  by $\to$-elim

> 5. $A \to B$ --- from 2) and 4)  by $\to$-intro, discharging [b].

Comment: The key is to build the proof from bottom up.  $$\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{{{\color{red}{\fitch{A\to(A\to B)}{~~\vdots\\~~\vdots\\~~\vdots\\A\to B}}}}\\(A\to(A\to B))\color{red}{\to}(A\to B)}\qquad\fitch{}{\fitch{A\to(A\to B)}{{{\color{red}{\fitch{A}{~~\vdots\\B}}}}\\A\color{red}{\to} B}\\(A\to(A\to B))\to(A\to B)}\qquad\fitch{}{\fitch{A\color{red}{\to}(A\to B)}{\fitch{A}{A\color{red}{\to} B\\B}\\A\to B}\\(A\to(A\to B))\to(A\to B)}$$